# Express.js 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have created new route "/bookroom" for my application, however, I keep getting an error:

POST http://localhost:3000/api/bookings/bookroom 400 (Bad Request)

I am not sure what is causing this error. Below I have listed the code from my frotnend and backend. I would be gratefull for any help.

Server.js

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const dbConfig = require('./db')
app.use(express.json())

const roomsRoute = require('./routes/roomsRoute')
const usersRoute = require('./routes/usersRoute')
const bookingsRoute = require('./routes/bookingsRoute')

app.use('/api/rooms', roomsRoute)
app.use('/api/users', usersRoute)
app.use('/api/bookings', bookingsRoute)

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

Backend - bookingsRoute.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Booking = require("../models/booking")


router.post("/bookroom", async(req, res)=>{
   const {
    room,
    userid,
    fromdate,
    todate,
    totalamount,
    totaldays} = req.body

    try{
        const newbooking = new Booking({
            room: room.name,
            roomid: room._id,
            userid,
            fromdate,
            todate,
            totalamount,
            totaldays,
            transactionId: '1234'
        })
        const booking = await newbooking.save()
        res.send('Room booked successfully')
    }catch(error){
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'error' });
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

Fronted - Bookingscreeen.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import Error from '../components/Error'
import moment from 'moment'


function Bookingscreen({ match }) {

  const [loading, setloading] = useState(true)
  const [error, seterror] = useState()
  const [room, setroom] = useState()

  const roomid = match.params.roomid
  const fromdate = moment(match.params.fromdate , 'DD-MM-YYYY')
  const todate = moment(match.params.todate , 'DD-MM-YYYY')
  const totaldays = moment.duration(todate.diff(fromdate)).asDays() + 1
  const [totalamount, settotalamount] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      setloading(true)
      async function gettingRoom() {
        const data = (await axios.post('/api/rooms/getroombyid', { roomid: match.params.roomid })).data
        setroom(data)
        setloading(false)
        settotalamount(data.rentperday * totaldays)
      }
      gettingRoom()
    }
    catch (error) {
      seterror(true)
      console.log(error)
      setloading(false)
    }
  }, [])

  async function bookRoom(){
    
    const bookingDetails = {
      room,
      userid: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))._id,
      fromdate,
      todate,
      totalamount,
      totaldays
    }
    
    try{
      const result = await axios.post('/api/bookings/bookroom', bookingDetails)
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='m-5'>
      {loading ?
        (<Loader />)
        : room ?
          (
            <div>
            <div className='row justify-content-center mt-6 bx_shadow'>
              <div className='col-md-5'>
                <h1>{room.name}</h1>
                <img src={room.imageurls[0]} classname='fullsizeimg' />
              </div>

              <div className='col-md-5'>
                <h1>Szczegóły rezerwacji</h1>
                <hr></hr>
                <b>
                  <p>Nazwa: {room.name} </p>
                  <p>Od: {match.params.fromdate}</p>
                  <p>Do: {match.params.todate}</p>
                  <p>Dni: {totaldays}</p>
                  <p>Cena za dzień: {room.rentperday} </p>
                  <p>Suma: {totalamount}</p>
                </b>
                <div>
                  <button style={{ float: 'right' }} className='room_btn' onClick={bookRoom}> Zarezerwuj</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>)
          : (<Error />)
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Bookingscreen
```

Model - bookings.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const bookingSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    room : {
        type: String, required: true
    },
    roomid : {
        type: String, required: true
    },
    userid : {
        type: String, required: true
    },
    fromdate : {
        type: String, required: true
    },
    todate : {
        type: String, required: true
    },
    totalamount : {
        type: Number, required: true
    },
    totaldays : {
        type: Number, required: true
    },
    transactionid : {
        type: String, required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String, required: true, default : "booked"
    }
},{
    timestamps: true,
})

const bookingmodel = mongoose.model('bookings', bookingSchema)

module.exports = bookingmodel
```

Comment: Your server is running locally on port 5000 but it seems the app is making API requests on port 3000 (*POST http://localhost:3000/api/bookings/bookroom 400 (Bad Request)*).

Comment: I have made all my other routes the same way and they have been working just fine. So I am not sure why this one whould be working differently.  Here you can see other request which is being used in Bookingscreen and this one is not causing any issues ```router.post("/getroombyid", async(req, res) => {
    const roomid = req.body.roomid
    try {
         const room = await Room.findOne({'_id' : req.body.roomid})
         res.send(room)
    } catch (error) {
         return res.status(400).json({ message: error });
    }
});
```

Comment: don't put 400 bad request in the catch block, try to use relevant error codes. and can you share error stack, do a console.log in the catch block and share

Comment: Here is the full error: https://pastebin.com/hG2Tdc6H
Short version: userid: ValidatorError: Path `userid` is required. Value: undefined. I believe that I am incorrectly getting user id here 
```userid: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))._id,``` Could you please advise how should I get this id?

Comment: OK, so you've reached `return res.status(400).json({ message: 'error' });`, presumably.  How about reporting the exception details with `message: error` instead of just the word `error` with `message: 'error'`?  Then we can find out what the server-side exception was because it will be put into the reply to the client.

Comment: I have changed that and now I am getting "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
Bookingscreen.js:52 Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)"

In the ide console I am getting an error with more details: https://pastebin.com/hG2Tdc6H

Comment: If you are receiving back a mongoose validation error response from the server then that means that `userid: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))._id,` in `bookRoom` didn't throw an error. The error implies `userid` is missing. Can you check the `userid` value in the sent `bookingDetails` object, and then also in the `req.body` object in the `"/bookroom"` endpoint handler and see what value was received there? What I suspect is that a defined object was stored in localStorage under `"currentUser"` but it is missing a `_id` property.

Comment: Thank you, I had to add .data before selecting ._id while assigning this value

Answer (score 0):

Your PORT ENV Is undefined currently so Your port is 5000. But you are requesting from localhost:3000

Comment: I don't think that is the case, because when I remove userid there is no issue. So I beleive I am incorrectly parsing userId here

userid: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))._id,


Do you know how can I fix that?